# Laravel file does not exist - file upload

Tags: php, file, upload, laravel

I am using a form to upload video files. For some reason all I get is the following error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpFoundation \ File \ Exception \ FileNotFoundException
The file "" does not exist
```

In my controller I had a validation rule to require files, like so

```
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
  array(
    'file'  => 'required'
  )
);
```

But because of the above rule, I couldn't properly debug what is going on, therefore I ended up removing it, as a result to generate the above error.

Comment: If you solved your problem please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it doesn't appear as "unanswered" anymore and serves as a future reference for others.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the php.ini file, change the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

This should make it work.

Comment: It would be best to leave a comment saying that this answer is taken from OP, rather than putting this note in the post itself (as we try to keep the noise out of posts). And most people would probably recommend making the post Community Wiki.

Comment: This is the best answer as I was stuck and could not find the actual reason and this did solve my issue

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is the "upload_max_filesize" that has been exceeded (check your php.ini), however it is a good practice to first check if the file is valid.

```
if (!$file->isValid()) {
    throw new \Exception('Error on upload file: '.$file->getErrorMessage());
}
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 with Laravel 5.8, I discovered this problem and your answers gave me clues, but I was still getting an error when I tried the `isValid` method. I found this was the best way to check if a file was too large:

```
    $file_result = new \stdClass();
    if ($request->file('file_to_upload')->getSize() === false) {
        $max_upload = min(ini_get('post_max_size'), ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
       //From: https://gist.github.com/svizion/2343619
        $max_upload = str_replace('M', '', $max_upload);
        $max_upload = $max_upload * 1024;
        $file_result->error = "The file you are trying to upload is too large. The maximum size is " . $max_upload;
        //return whatever json_encoded data your client-side app expects.
    }
```

It looks as if the `getSize` method successfully returns false if the file size exceeds the maximum size. In my experience `isValid` throws an obscure error. The upload_max_filesize parameter is there to protect the server so I wanted a reliable way of catching when the user attempts to upload a large file and my client-side validation is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To clear the answer
The problem that you uploaded file which size is more than php configuration located in php.ini, so when you try to access the any property of the uploadFile object you will see the exception because file not exist

Comment: This was addressed in 2014 + The accepted answer states the changes to be made in the php.ini file.