# Laravel 5 The file "" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload a file. Heres my controller

```
if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $destinationPath = 'images/quizzes/'; // upload path
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image

            $request['photo'] = $fileName;
            $request['image_path'] = $destinationPath;

            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path

            $quiz = Quiz::create($request->all())


        }else{
            \Session::flash('flash_message_delete','Please select files to upload.');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

It gives me `FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37:The file "" does not exist`. This was working fine the other day, idk what happes..i try to interchange the arrangement like:

```
$destinationPath = 'images/quizzes/'; // upload path
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renameing image

            $request['photo'] = $fileName;
            $request['image_path'] = $destinationPath;

            $quiz = Quiz::create($request->all());

            $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
```

I wont have error like this, and it save to the database, THE PROBLEM is the `photo field` instead of the `$filename` it has wierd `/tmp/somestrings` inserted.

Comment: what is the code on line 37 ?

Comment: What the size of the file you are uploading?

Comment: File.php is from laravel, i try to upload 400Kb file. Also I noticed that it was uploaded in the images before give me errors since the file was there.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388926/laravel-file-does-not-exist-file-upload

Comment: it doesn't fix my problem, this is really wierd, it was working just fine then got this error