# The file "" does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post, filesystems

I want to upload a file on jobs request page in my site but after upload file on my page, I'm getting the following error:

> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException The file "" does not exist

My code is:

```
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public');
echo $path;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel file does not exist - file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388926/laravel-file-does-not-exist-file-upload)

Comment: check file exists in request 
`dd($request->hasFile('image'));`

Comment: please show your form, and say your code is on local or server?

Comment: @Anas Alweish i try this solution but it did'nt solve.

Comment: @amini.swallow my form is 


<form action="{{ URL::to('/testjob')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" value=" {{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

Answer (score 2):

In the php.ini file, change the following codes:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

I hope it works

Comment: what is the size of your file?because I had this problem before

Comment: my file size is 80Kb

Answer (score 0):

Very obvious but still bit me sometimes:

Make sure your file input field is set as required.

`<input name="image" type="file" required>`

Forgetting to set it required will make it possible to upload empty files which causes this exact error message.